# clojure case switch. How about the last line?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn explain-defcon-level [exercise-term]
  (case exercise-term
        :fade-out          :you-and-what-army
        :double-take       :call-me-when-its-important
        :round-house       :o-rly
        :fast-pace         :thats-pretty-bad
        :cocked-pistol     :sirens
        :say-what?))
```

For this code piece, Other the last line, I understand them.
it uses keyword to look up values.
But last line, why there is a question mark and there is no value corresponding to it.
need some explanations. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

it's the default. it will return `say-what?`, if no other clause matches.  the question mark means nothing here, as keywords may just contain "any" char.

see http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case.

> A single
>   default expression can follow the clauses, and its value will be
>   returned if no clause matches. If no default expression is provided
>   and no clause matches, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.